# What is the difference between overriding ToString and using implicit/explicit conversion operators in C#?

Tags: c#

In C#, what is the difference between this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "Person: " + Name;
}
```

And this:

```
public static implicit/explicit operator string(Person person)
{
    return "Person: " + Name;
}
```

Comment: Semantics is different. Conversion operator says "convert to string type" (as to any other type). `ToString` means "give me (usually human) readable text representation of the object.

Comment: Great answer! Could you put it in an answer? :)

Comment: Not sure it deserves to be an answer, but if you wish :)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semantics is somewhat different.

[Conversion operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx) say "*convert to string (or another) type*":

> C# enables programmers to declare conversions on classes or structs so that classes or structs can be converted to and/or from other classes or structs, or basic types.

[`Object.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) supposed to return

> A string that represents the current object.

meaning "*give me (usually human) readable text representation of the object*".

(I'm not saying though that such semantics is always respected. E.g. sometimes you may see `ToString` and `FromString` are used as conversion functions.)

Comment: That explain that very well! Great, quick answer!

Comment: A question. If I convert to string implicitly, should I also override `ToString()`? Since every time I use an instance of the class in a string context it automatically converts to `string` (or does it?).

Comment: @Sipo "_every time I use an instance of the class in a string context it automatically converts to `string`_" Not really, `ToString` is usually called by functions like `Console.WriteLine` which expect [`object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx). BTW, the debugger also uses `ToString` when dumps the content of a class instance. Overriding `ToString` is often a good practice.

Comment: Thanks. But if I do not override `ToString()` and use and implicit conversion, when I pass my instance to `Console.WriteLine()` it is still working. Why?

Comment: Perhaps you mean something like `Console.WriteLine(x)`, I'm talking rather about `Console.WriteLine("{0}", x)`. In the first case, `Console.WriteLine(string)` is called (a function which expects a single parameter of type `string`), and conversion from `x` to `string` happens. Without the implicit operator, `Console.WriteLine(object)` would be called, leading to printing of `x.ToString()`.